# 2 web services on the same server but in different folders

Tags: c#, web-services

so i had j query calling one web service and it worked fine. i then wanted to create a duplicate so that i could keep one up at all time and use the second for testing. the original sits in the root directory and the new one sits in a folder called test. the test folder induces the asmx file along with the config and bin folder. the html file which calls the jquery sits in the test folder as well and has been modified to call test/service.asmx rather than just service.asmx. however the websevice in the root directory is being run rather than the test one when i call for the test service to be run. chrome says that the test service is being called and i even renamed the test service to servicefortests to differentiate them.

any clues???

Answer (score 1):

That seems a bit strange to me.  I would recommend setting it up on a different server completely if you have that ability.  If not, I would at least set it up as a different web application in IIS.  As it sits right now, if you were to run away with the worker process in test, it would also impact production.  That could also solve your issue since it may be referencing the same bin.